# Batch script copy files with suffix

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, if-statement, robocopy

In my `pic` folder I have multiple `.jpg` pictures, some of them with suffix `_ok`,  or `_psd`.
I want to copy all my `.jpg` files into my `sel` subfolder, but if my `.jpg` file has also a suffix version, I want to copy only the suffix version.

My example folder contains:

```
A.jpg
B.jpg
C.jpg
C_OK.jpg
D.jpg
D_psd.jpg
```

I want to copy only `A.jpg`, `B.jpg`, `C_OK.jpg`, and `D_psd.jpg`.

I began the loop and I'm already lost with the `if` statement.

```
for /D %%i in ("C:\pic\*") do ROBOCOPY C:\pic *.jpg C:\pic\sel\
```

NB : I use robocopy because xcopy doesn't work in my batch files,(only in cmd).

Comment: Open a Command Prompt window and enter `for /?`, as your use with its `/D` option seems wrong, _even if you were using it properly_.